# Can I completely disable signatures in reply in Gmail?

Tags: gmail

When searching for this question, all I could find is how to disable the option.

> Insert this signature before quoted text in replies and remove the "--" line that precedes it.

But this would not *remove* the signature and they still pile up at the end of the email. Is there a way to disable the signatures in replies, or even better, to prevent the signature from being added if the same signature exists already somewhere in the (quoted) text of the email?

Comment: Only in replies. I like to have my signature once in an email thread, but not more than that.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the only way is to hide them with `--`.

The workaround would be to disable signatures completely and use canned responses, but the downside would be always inserting canned response, e.g. it would be signature on demand.

Comment: What a pity. Maybe something will be implemented in the future.

Comment: How the hiding part does work exactly?

Comment: I don't ask If it does work. But how should I use it.  The "hide them with --" is not self explanatory. Where do I put it?

Comment: @WooYek https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/gmail/WB8X-4-EkPU ... https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/gmail/MXwTovrWp-w ... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=poESZqihmKs ... https://support.xink.io/support/solutions/articles/1000228799-how-to-stop-the-signature-piling-up-at-the-end-of-a-long-thread-

Comment: This does not _hide_ signatures at all it configures signature placement _on the end_ or just _after the reply_ and before quoted message.